# Java: unhandled exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, try-catch

I would like to handle an exception but the Eclipse editor is giving me tips which  I'm not understanding. This is the method's code:

```java
    public Collection<String> listOfFriends(String codePerson)
            throws NoSuchCodeException {

        Collection<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            people.get(codePerson).getFriendsCodes().forEach( code -> s.add(getPerson(code)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
```

Where getPerson is:

```java
    public String getPerson(String code) throws NoSuchCodeException {
        if(!people.containsKey(code)){
            throw new NoSuchCodeException();
        }
        return people.get(code).getCode() + " " + people.get(code).getName() + " " + people.get(code).getSurname();
```

and the exception is:

```java
public class NoSuchCodeException extends Exception {
    NoSuchCodeException(){}
    NoSuchCodeException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Eclipse returns two errors in the `listOfFriends` method, one where `getPerson()` is invoked, saying "Unhandled exception type NoSuchCodeException" and the other one in the catch row, saying "Unreacheable catch block for NoSuchCodeException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body".

PS: I added try and catch in the `listOfFriends` method just to try to solve the problem, since, as far as I know, given that the method has in its declaration "throws NoSuchCodeException", it shouldn't be obligatory, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `NoSuchCodeException`.

Comment: did you import `NoSuchCodeException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the lambda function. The interface of the function that `forEach` requires doesn't declare any kind of checked exceptions: take a look at `java.util.function.Consumer`. That's the place where the first issue occurs, the second one is simply a result of the first one.

Either you should make `NoSuchCodeException` extend `RuntimeException` or add a `try catch` block to you lambda. I would suggest you to stick to the first solution, unless `NoSuchCodeException` is something that may occur under normal conditions.

Also take a look at this question: [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer, I added a `try catch` block and the error finally disappeared. But, about the PS of the first post, since the method `listOfFriends` is declared specifying that it `throws NoSuchCodeException`, why is it obligatory to handle it? Is it because `forEach` can't "pass it up" to `listOfFriends` ?

Comment: @RVKS, yes, because `forEach` "can't pass it up", precisely because it doesn't support any checked exceptions at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to catch that exception inside of the `forEach` block.  Since `forEach` isn't declared to handle exceptions, you have to help it along the way.

The alternative is to change your exception into an unchecked exception, but that may not work for your particular use case.

```
try {
    people.get(codePerson).getFriendsCodes().forEach(code -> {
        try {
            s.add(getPerson(code));
        } catch (NoSuchCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```